# Issues with $push in mongo

Tags: c, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-c-driver

I am running into a problem and I am not sure how to fix it.  Any help you can provide would be great, I am sure it is something stupid I am doing wrong. :)

I am trying to $push some items into an array titled "subscribed_tribes".  Here is my document prior to any pushes:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5693fc1f6890f14daa0e26e1"), 
"password" : "7CAE......", 
"salt" : "748D...", 
"created" : ISODate("2016-01-11T19:01:51.000+0000"), 
"display_name" : "2686....", 
"my_tribes" : "", 
"subscribed_tribes" : ""
}
```

---

When I run the following c code nothing happens (no changes).

```
        collection = mongoc_client_get_collection (client, "STribe", "users");

        query = bson_new ();
        bson_oid_t oid;
        char *techSupportID = "5693c0196890f159c1741bb1";
        bson_oid_init_from_string (&oid, techSupportID);
        query = BCON_NEW ("_id", BCON_OID(&oid));

        // Find the document
        cursor = mongoc_collection_find (collection, MONGOC_QUERY_NONE, 0, 0, 0, query, NULL, NULL);

        update = bson_new ();
        //BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (update, "testing", "blah");
        //mongoc_collection_update (collection, MONGOC_UPDATE_NONE, query, update, NULL, &error);


        // Assemble query
        update = BCON_NEW ("$push", 
            "{", 
                "subscribed_tribes", 
                    "{", 
                        "tribe_id",     BCON_UTF8 (tribe_id), 
                        "tribe_key",  BCON_UTF8 (passphrase), 
                    "}", 
            "}");
        mongoc_collection_update (collection, MONGOC_UPDATE_NONE, query, update, NULL, &error);
```

If I uncomment the two lines of code (bson_append and mongc_collection_update) then the entire document is overwritten and replaced with:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5693c0196890f159c1741bb1"), 
"testing" : "blah", 
"subscribed_tribes" : [
    {
        "tribe_id" : "5624200d4bacd3940b8b2d62", 
        "tribe_key" : "27D719EDC7A59...."
    }
]
}
```

Any ideas why the original code doesn't add the array item into subscribed_tribes correctly?  Secondly why does the inclusion of the uncommented lines overwrite the entire document?

Once again I am sure I am doing something stupid, but I am just not sure what.

Comment: @JohnnyHK  I feel so stupid, you are right!

Comment: I believe that the downvotes you received yesterday are not due to the quality of your posts, but because of the meta-effect. Your editing behaviour is being discussed there and it has become a hot-meta post by now: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users?cb=1

Comment: @Adriaan -- Thank you for the headsup, I figured it was some troll downvoting me rather than provide constructive criticism

Comment: To leave some constructive criticism for this specific post: it's not according to SO-policy to add an answer within the question itself. The question itself will remain for the question part, whilst an answer, if any, will be posted as such and accepted if it worked. I'd therefore suggest removing the answer from here, either asking JohnnyHK to edit it in, or add your own answer, pointing to his fix.

Comment: @Adriaan -- Ok thank you, I just wanted to make sure that anyone else having the same issues had the working fix fully detailed.  I'll clean it up.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subscribed_tribes` is currently a string, not an array. That's why you can't use `$push` on it.

If you inspect the populated `error` result, you should be getting an error message about that.

So your doc needs to look like this for `$push` to work:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5693fc1f6890f14daa0e26e1"), 
"password" : "7CAE......", 
"salt" : "748D...", 
"created" : ISODate("2016-01-11T19:01:51.000+0000"), 
"display_name" : "2686....", 
"my_tribes" : "", 
"subscribed_tribes" : []
}
```